# Search a subtext in an specific field in bash

Tags: bash, search

I have a `string=word1:word2:word3:word4:word5` and I want to search a word but only in the filed 4 (word4).
I mean if I search with grep "word4" and `string=word4:word3:word1:word2` did not show this line, it should only show it if `string=a:b:c:word4:d`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please be more clear in your question as it is NOT at clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo *"$string"* | awk -F : '{ print $4 }' | grep -i "word4"
```

Comment: `echo "$string"`, not `echo $string`. Otherwise, if you have a whitespace-surrounded `*`, you'll have a list of filenames in your output.

Comment: Also, you can just `awk -F: 'tolower($4) ~ /word4/ { print "Match found" }'` and not need `grep` at all. (Or do all the logic in bash and not need awk either, but... well, that's what my answer is doing).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  there's several approach to handle with it, depending on users level, i'm using my self the one in ur answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string=word1:word2:word3:word4:word5
IFS=: read -r w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 _ <<<"$string"
if [[ $w4 = *"word4"* ]]; then
  echo "Match!"
fi
```

References:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *"How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"*